# MongoDB - move documents to archive and delete them from original collection

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections:

- A (original)
- B (archive)

I want to move all documents, which match some condition, to collection B (archive) and original documents from collection A remove. I use Python and so far I have this:

```
db.A.aggregate([{"$match": {"$and": [{"attribute1": False}, {"attribute2": False}]} }, {"$out": "B"} ])

db.A.deleteMany({"$and": [{"attribute1": False}, {"attribute2": False}]})
```

Both commands work, but when I call *deleteMany* on collection A it also deletes new documents in archive B. I guess Mongo keeps it like one object and share some kind of pointer and that's why it removes from both collections. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: No it does not. MongoDB does not have a "shared pointer" of any kind. But I'm guessing you did not read the documentation on [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) which actually specifically says it "overwrites" the target collection. So every invocation is deleting the content that was there before, and not "appending" to it. And that is the "actual" behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Also you have a useless usage of `$and` here. MongoDB query arguments are "already" **AND** conditions. `{ "attribute1": False, "attribute2": False }` does the exact same thing, whilst being cleaner and clearer to read and understand.

Comment: You are right. Is there a solution how to do it properly? I mean any different command for $out, which works as I need?

Comment: Well the "method" to "append" data to an existing collection is to `.insert()` or "upsert" using `.update()` as is appropriate. Ideally done with Bulk operations such as the [`.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) interface. But simply sending an expression to the server and having it "append" to a an existing collection in the way the `$out` overwrites, well that does not exist. Performing a standard query and processing the loop of results is considered the standard practice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for Python:

```
documents = db.A.find({"attribute1": False, "attribute2": False})
if documents.count() != 0:
    db.B.insert_many(documents)
    db.A.remove({"attribute1": False, "attribute2": False})
```